# Add multiple rows in a SQL SELECT query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I have a table and I want to write a `query` which will give duplicate rows of that table based on the value of column `quantity` in that table.

Suppose the table is one given below

```
 name | quantity
------|----------
  a   |  1
  b   |  1
  c   |  3
  d   |  2
  e   |  1
```

And I want to be able to write a `query` in `T-SQL` so that it would give a result which would look like follows;

```
 name | number | quantity
------|--------|----------
  a   |  1     |    1
  b   |  1     |    1
  c   |  1     |    3
  c   |  2     |    3
  c   |  3     |    3
  d   |  1     |    2
  d   |  2     |    2
  e   |  1     |    1
```

So in this result, there are 3 rows for "c" as its quantity is 3 and the number increments as the line appears for nth time.

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12816520/sql-select-selective-row-multiple-times) which has been answered and accepted, but I don't quite understand how to apply it in to my scenario. Any help on this is much appreciated..!

Comment: Take a look at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
 With Ints(n) As
 (Select 1 Union All
  Select n + 1 From Ints
  Where n < 1000)    
 Select t.Name, i.n 
 from myTable t join Ints i 
   on i.n <= t.Quantity
 option(MaxRecursion 1000)
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a numbers table and do a join:

```
with numbers as (
      select 1 as n
      union all
      select 1 + n
      from numbers
      where 1 + n <= 50
    )
select t.name, numbers.n, t.quantity
from t join
     numbers
     on t.quantity <= numbers.n;
```

This assumes the maximum quantity is 50.  You could put in `select max(quantity) from t)` if you wanted it more flexible.

If `quantity` can be big, you might want to add `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have sql server now. I think  `DENSE_RANK`  is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would create a table with numbers thus:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Number(Num INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.Number
DEFAULT VALUES; -- this will insert 10000 rows into dbo.Number table (all numbers between 1 and 10000)
GO 10000
```

Then, I would create a constraint just to be sure that quantity column cann't contains values greater than 10000:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_MyTable_Quantity CHECK(Quantity BETWEEN 1 AND 10000);
```

And the solution:

```
SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.name ORDER BY @@SPID) AS number
FROM dbo.MyTable t INNER JOIN dbo.Number n ON t.Quantity <= n.Num;
```

Note #1: This solution assumes that Quantity column is mandatory (NOT NULL) and has an integer data type ([TINY|SMALL|BIG]INT, NUMERIC|DECIMAL(p,0)).

Note #2: This solution assumes that minimum QTY is 1 and maximum QTY is 10000.